# Winforms web browser control not firing document complete with AJAX web site

Tags: html, vb.net, ajax, automation, webbrowser-control

The VB.Net desktop app uses the IE browser control to navigate the web. When a normal page loads the document_complete event fires and I can read the resulting page and go from there. The issue I am having is that the page I am driving is written with AJAX, so the document complete event never fires. Furthermore, when you view the source of the page after it loaded a new portion via AJAX, it hasn't change. How are people handling this? What are my options?

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, AJAX/Javascript/CSS/VBS/whatever doesn't modify the source, they modify the DOM

Comment: Does an event get fired in VB.Net when the DOM gets fired?

Answer (score 1):

This solution might solve your problem.
prerequists:
AxwebBrowser control,
reference to mshtml.dll

Dim axmshtml As mshtml.HTMLDocument = YourAxWebBrowserControl.Document

Dim HTMLSource As String = axmshtml.body.innerHTML 'html source, including DOM changes

If you know what you are looking for you can put the above code in a timer/loop
  and simply monitor the page source for changes.

Answer (score 1):

If wb is your webbrowser control, then instead of getting the HTML by using:

```
wb.DocumentText
```

use:

```
wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml
```

This will give you the updated html, reflecting the AJAX update.

As to detecting when the AJAX completes, for me it seems to be triggering a DocumentCompleted event. Not sure why it's different for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interact with the Javascript code in the website using the methods on `HtmlDocument`.

Comment: Am I monitoring another event in VB.Net? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this kind of behavior with C# when some AJAX scripts created a race condition. Adding [the defer attribute](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/) to the script tag helped in that case. YMMV.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I can't edit the web site - it's not mine. I am simply driving the control around and working with the resulting pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work.

When the Ajax call completes, add a random anchor hash to the URL like so: foo.html#23234
then add your code to the NavigateComplete2 event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768334%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: But how do I know when the AJAX call is complete? Does something fire?

Comment: Not sure what framework you are using but with the core api, you know the load is complete in the onreadystatechange event

 function onSumResponse() {
   if (xhReq.readyState != 4)  { return; }
   var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
   ...
 }
 ...
 var xhReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "sumGet.phtml?figure1=5&figure2=10", true);
 xhReq.onreadystatechange = onSumResponse;
 xhReq.send(null);

ref: http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the page your load in your windows app does an AJAX call, which appears to refresh the page. In that case, the document_complete event isn't fired, because the webpage itself isn't refreshed, but a **portion** of the page.

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279450/how-do-you-check-for-ajax-updates-using-a-webbrowser-control-in-net-2-0) about this problem, with an accepted answer in VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProgressChanged event, it seems to fire during ajax calls